# how to resolve (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I'm trying to create an update script for Fast Node Manager (fnm) which will prompt the user to update fnm whenever a new major version (like 1.26.0) is released and the minor versions (like 1.25.1) are ignored.
Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get the latest version
latestVersion=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/Schniz/fnm/releases/latest | grep tag_name | cut -d ":" -f2 | cut -d "," -f1 | cut -d "v" -f2 | cut -d "." -f1,2)

# get currently installed version
installedVersion=$(fnm -V | cut -d " " -f2 | cut -d "." -f1,2)
insane="1.0.0"
# statement to be printed if fnm is already up to date
upToDateMessage="${spacing} Your fnm version is up to date."

# statement to be printed if fnm needs to be updated
outdatedMessage="${spacing} Your fnm version is outdated! The currently installed version is "$installedVersion" while the latest version is "$latestVersion". Do you wish to update fnm (y/n): "

echo -e "${spacing} Checking for updates..."
echo -e "${N}"

# the main if-else statement
if [[ $(bc <<< "$insane >= $latestVersion") -eq 1 ]]; then
   echo -e $upToDateMessage
else
   echo -e $outdatedMessage
   read user_input
     if [ $user_input == y ]; then
       echo -e "${spacing} Updating fnm..."
       $(curl -fsSL https://fnm.vercel.app/install | bash)
     elif [ $user_input == n ]; then
       echo -e "${spacing} Thanks for using this script."
       exit
     else
       echo -e "${spacing} Invalid input! Please answer in y or n."
       exit
   fi
fi
```

The `$insane` is for testing purposes only (because I already have the latest version i.e. 1.25.0 installed) and will be removed in production. Everything is fine when the version codes are same. But, when I use the `$insane` for comparing the version codes, the output comes

```
 Note: Minor versions are ignored for now. 

 Checking for updates...

(standard_in) 1: syntax error
Your fnm version is outdated! The currently installed version is 1.25 while the latest version is 1.25. Do you wish to update fnm (y/n):
n
 Thanks for using this script.
```

Please help me to resolve the `(standard_in) 1: syntax error` error :)

Comment: How about you remove everything except about three lines where you set `latestVersion`, `insane`, and the `bc` command? See [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming from this line:

```
if [[ $(bc <<< "$insane >= $latestVersion") -eq 1 ]]
```

`$insane` is `1.0.0`, which is not a valid number, since it has two decimal points. `bc` is a mathematical calculator, it only works with proper numbers.

When the code sets `$latestVersion` and `$installedVersion`, it uses `cut -d "." -f1,2`, so they will only have one decimal point. You should use a similar format for `$insane`.

It's not clear why you're comparing with `$insane` in the first place. If you want to know if your version is up to date, you should compare with `$installedVersion`.

This also seems like a problem:

```
$(curl -fsSL https://fnm.vercel.app/install | bash)
```

You shouldn't have it inside `$(...)`. That will try to execute the output of the script as another command line. Simply piping the `curl` output to `bash` is enough to execute it.

```
curl -fsSL https://fnm.vercel.app/install | bash
```

And you use undefined variables `${spacing}` and `${N}` in a number of places.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the value of ```$insane``` from ```1.0.0``` to ```1.0``` and it worked :)

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand how that comparison means the installed version is up to date.

Comment: ```$insane``` was just for testing and it will be removed once the code works fine. I have the latest version of fnm so, my if logic will always return true to me (unless I install an outdated version) but I also wanted to test what happens when if logic returns false. So, I used ```$insane```. So, there's no use of ```$insane``` in the final code. Simple :) BTW, forgive me, I responded too late :b